# Formating column range displays "#VALUE" instead of value

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I am using

```
var outputColumn = source_sheet.getRange("V:Y"); 
// Set the formats for the columns to be GBP £
```

to format the values in a number of columns to GBP. However on running the script, the cells in the column displayed "#VALUE". 
Thinking I had erred, I removed the lines of code and ran the script again. This did not make a difference. So I added another set of data to ckeck if the change applied to the new set of data. Sadly not.
Then I tried

```
var outputColumn = source_sheet.getRange("V:Y");               
outputColumn.clearFormat();
```

but this made no difference either. ClearFormat should have cleared out all formatting leaving the contents in place. Alas not so.
The intriguing aspect is that when I click on the cell, the actiual value I would have expected in the call is stored. BUT the display is "#VALUE".

I am confused as to what it can be. The lines of code are simple and no errors shown. The clearFormat() does not appear to do the trick.

Ideas please?

Comment: Can you debug that by using console.log() and see if you're really displaying a valid value?

Comment: I have used Logger.log but that did not shed light on the issue.
Reviewing tutorials & various developer boards/posts etc) still left me in the same state. Through experimentation, managed to resolve most of it  The small snag I am still hung up on is that I unable to show the leading ‘0’ before a decimal point when formatting ‘%’ numbers. Any ideas?
I am using :
var columnKP = source_sheet.getRange("K:P");                 // Set  %
      columnKP.setNumberFormat("0#.0#%");

Comment: you're using Logger.log? The tag should be Apps Script.

Comment: If you have selected that range in sheet, it will not work as the manual edit has more priority that script (there will be lock on that range).